# better implementation of on click toggle class jquery

Tags: jquery, class, toggle

Hello I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have some jquery code which adds a class to specific Divs in my page. I was wondering if there was a better way to implement the code, because it is glitchy. I have 5 Div IDs which i would like to add a visible class to. I also have one class which applies to all the div elements which should toggle an active class. I am fairly new to jquery and not sure if this is the proper way to implement it, please see my code below:

```
$('.graph-button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});    

//Get the Circles to Show text boxes by adding class
$('#value_button').click(function(){
  $('#value_text').toggleClass("visible");
});
$('#history_button').click(function(){
  $('#history_text').toggleClass("visible");
});
$('#vision_button').click(function(){
  $('#vision_text').toggleClass("visible");
});
$('#offering_button').click(function(){
  $('#offering_text').toggleClass("visible");
});
$('#future_button').click(function(){
  $('#future_text').toggleClass("visible");
});
```

I would really appreciate the help. CHEERS!

Comment: can you include the html or a jsfiddle. depending on how your html is there could be several ways to improve the jquery

Comment: hey @depperm thanks for the reply please find the codepen here https://codepen.io/YoungDali/pen/QKdqGk

Comment: what specifically is glitchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just toggle the class of the next element anytime a button is pressed

```
$('.graph-button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next().toggleClass("visible");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @depperm, I really appreciate it!.

Answer (score 0):

If the divs are not consecutive you can build the id of the next div starting from the current id:

```
$('#' + this.id.split('_')[0] + '_text')
```

And you may select all the divs with attribute value finish with:

```
$('[id$=_button]')
```

So the snippet could be:

```js
//Get the circles to change border color by adding class
//Get the Circles to Show text boxes by adding class
$('[id$=_button]').click(function(){
  $('#' + this.id.split('_')[0] + '_text').toggleClass("visible");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
/*--------------- Global Styles--------------*/
body{background-color:black;}

.align-center{

  text-align:center;

}

.align-right{
  text-align:right;
}

.align-left{
  text-align:left;
}

/*--Buttons--*/
.graph-button{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 13px solid rgb(103, 199, 216)           !important;
  width: 79px;
  height: 79px;
  transform-origin: 47.5px 47.5px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: 0.5s ease;

}
.graph-button:hover:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -25px;
  top:-25px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.graph-button:hover:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -40px;
  top: -40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.graph-button p{

  text-align:center !important;
  color:rgb(40, 67, 116);
  font-weight:bold;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
  line-height:3;
}
.active{

  border: 13px solid rgb(40, 67, 116) !important;
  transition: border 0.5s ease;
}
.active p{
  color:rgb(103, 199, 216);
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
.graph-button:after {
  animation: sonarWave 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.graph-button:before {
  animation: sonarWave 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.graph-button:active{
  animation: pulse .5s ease;

}
/*--Buttons--*/


/*--Animations--*/
@keyframes sonarWave {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.2);
  }
  5% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.8);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {

  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);

  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);

  }
}

/*--Animations--*/
/*--Text Boxes--*/

.graph-text{

  max-width:25%;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;

}
.graph-text h2{

  color:white;

}
.graph-text p{

  color:white;

}
.visible{
  visibility: visible !important;
}

/*--Text Boxes--*/

/*--------------- Global Styles--------------*/



/*--------------- Custom Styles--------------*/

.value-button{

  left: 691px;
  top: 227px;
}
.value-text{

  left: 550px;
  top: 50px;
}

.history-button{
  left: 520px;
  top: 349px;
}
.history-text{

  left: 105px;
  top: 300px;

}

.vision-button{
  left: 587px;
  top: 548px;
}
.vision-text{
  left: 175px;
  top: 510px;
}

.offering-button{
  left: 793px;
  top: 549px;
}
.offering-text{
  left: 925px;
  top: 510px;
}

.future-button{
  left: 854px;
  top: 349px;
}
.future-text{
  left: 980px;
  top: 300px;
}

.center-circle{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 179px;
  height: 179px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  left:645px;
  top:360px;
  padding:0.5%;
}
.center-circle-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
}
.center-circle-text h1{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2em;
  color:rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.98);
}
.center-circle-text h2{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.7em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:rgb(40, 67, 116);
}
.center-circle-text h3{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1em;
  color:rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.98);
}

/*--------------- Custom Styles--------------*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="value-button graph-button" id="value_button">
    <p>sample</p>
</div>
<div class="value-text graph-text align-center" id="value_text">
    <h2>This is a Heading </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui at augue elitr, eu cum voluptua efficiendi. Ius odio facilis eu, verear epicuri voluptatibus ut pri. Sed ut brute dolor, cu vidit illum tincidunt mea.</p>

</div>



<div class="history-button graph-button" id="history_button">
    <p>sample</p>
</div>
<div class="history-text graph-text align-right" id="history_text">
    <h2>This is a Heading </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui at augue elitr, eu cum voluptua efficiendi. Ius odio facilis eu, verear epicuri voluptatibus ut pri. Sed ut brute dolor, cu vidit illum tincidunt mea.</p>

</div>


<div class="vision-button graph-button" id="vision_button">
    <p>sample</p>
</div>

<div class="vision-text graph-text align-right" id="vision_text">
    <h2>This is a Heading </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui at augue elitr, eu cum voluptua efficiendi. Ius odio facilis eu, verear epicuri voluptatibus ut pri. Sed ut brute dolor, cu vidit illum tincidunt mea.</p>

</div>


<div class="offering-button graph-button" id="offering_button">
    <p>sample</p>
</div>
<div class="offering-text graph-text align-left" id="offering_text">
    <h2>This is a Heading </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui at augue elitr, eu cum voluptua efficiendi. Ius odio facilis eu, verear epicuri voluptatibus ut pri. Sed ut brute dolor, cu vidit illum tincidunt mea.</p>

</div>



<div class="future-button graph-button" id="future_button">
    <p>sample</p>
</div>
<div class="future-text graph-text align-left" id="future_text">
    <h2>This is a Heading </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui at augue elitr, eu cum voluptua efficiendi. Ius odio facilis eu, verear epicuri voluptatibus ut pri. Sed ut brute dolor, cu vidit illum tincidunt mea.</p>

</div>


<!-- <div class="center-circle">
<div class="center-circle-text">
 <h1>sample</h1>
<h2>sample</h2>
 <h3>sample</h3>
</div> -->

<div class="pentagon">

</div>
```